# GroupBy And Select In Single Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using lambda expression, how can I group an entity and select only a property of the entity into that group list?

For example:

I want to group `Students` by `Name` and select their `ID`s. Hence, the result will be `List<List<int>>`.

Doing `Students.GroupBy(s=>s.Name).Select(s=>s.ID).ToList()` does not work?

I can do it in two stages but I want to send a single query to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you group something the result is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping>` where `IGrouping` is really just an `IEnumerable` with a `Key` property. So you have to select your `Id`s in from each grouping and convert them into a list.

```
Students.GroupBy(s=>s.Name).Select(group => group.Select(s => s.ID).ToList()).ToList()
```

Comment: Just an fyi - typo! `group => grouop.Select`